# Local SQL DB Insert fails, no error given

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to insert a record into a table in a local SQL DB using Visual Studio 2015. The code never returns an error, but yet the record is never actually inserted.

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand inscmd = new SqlCommand();
    inscmd.Connection = conn;
    inscmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Attendance (StudentID,DatePresent) VALUES (@StudentID, @DatePresent)";
    inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", intStudentId);
    inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePresent", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    inscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show(((ExtendedButton)sender).Text + " has been marked as present.");
    conn.Close();
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

When I run the code, the message box pops up stating that the student has been added to the attendance record. When I close the app to look at the actual data in the table, though; that data is not present.

My "Catch" message box never appears.

Comment: What is your connection string? What count is returned from `ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: @nikhilvartak My connection string is the same I use for a Select Statement in an earlier void.
When I run and break the code at the line just after the ExecuteNonQuery() statement, it says in my watch window:
    System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery returned 1
Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: dont happen to have 2 databases do you?

Comment: What about my 2nd question?

Comment: So waht is the connection string? One of those where the database is a copy that is made when you start debugging? That is the standard issue people have.

Comment: Sorry, @nikhilvartak; hit enter too early. My comment has been edited.
No, @JamieD77; at least not that I know of. My Server Explorer only shows the one data connection; though it does consistently have a red X until I click on it or one of my tables -- then it goes away.

Comment: Possibly safe updates is on?  Try running the query `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` then run your code again

Comment: @TomTom This is the connection string in my app.config: Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\YouthTrack.mdf;Integrated Security=True

Comment: Use Profiler to see what you are actually sending. Likely you are not sending an actual insert to the server.

Comment: @Joris That query fails; perhaps because it's a local DB?

Comment: @HLGEM Do you mean Visual Studio Profiler or SQL Server Profiler? This is a local MDF database; I'm not sure I can run profiler on it...

Comment: @pmbasehore what kind of db is it?  I ask because the command I gave you was for a mysql db

Comment: @Joris MSSQL Local DB, as part of the Data Tools in Visual Studio.

Comment: SQl Server profiler which you should be able to attach to any SQl server database and see what was being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ExecuteNonQuery returns 1, that means it has affected 1 row. So, it looks like the command is working and something else is occurring. Either you're not looking at the right place, or the right table or something; or the row is being deleted by either a trigger that removes it, or a rollback transaction later on - either explicitly or implicitly. You could try explicitly committing before closing.

So, you need to check further into your code or DB.

Comment: So after further research, I learned that the Server Explorer and SQL Server Object Explorer don't show the same information. Server Explorer shows empty data, but the Object Explorer shows that there are separate databases created; one for debug and one for release. Thanks for the advice -- I thought my code looked correct!